# Tracking Video Plays in Google Analytics

Tags: stash, video, tracking, analytics, google-analytics

So I have a rescue client running EE 2.10.1  where the client has a number of videos across the site that he wants to track plays. Can anyone provide pointers on how I can achieve this? I'm not very familiar with GA, usually just drop the code into the site and I'm done with it. Here is a quote from my client

> On my Vendor Entry Form Page I have a Vendor Tracking Code at the
>   bottom. I then use this code on my Article Pages, Manufacture Pages,
>   Redirect Pages. This allow me to run my GA Report using that code and
>   all the activity show up on one report per client. This is what I use
>   to charge my clients.
>
> On the Vendor Entry Form, I can add Video. However when the video is
>   watched, it doesn't get tracked. No Video is being tracked on my site.
>   I would like to add the vendor code somehow so that when the Video is
>   clicked on and watch, that activity url shows up on my report also.

Looking at the current GA code I see a bit of custom code being sent that looks similar to this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

specifically:

```
ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'Videos',
  eventAction: 'play',
  eventLabel: 'Fall Campaign'
});
```

Would I be able to add that into this bit of the GA code and not break anything?

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-*******', 'auto');
  ga('set', 'dimension1', '{exp:stash:client_code}');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at Google Tag Manager. I use it to inject GA code into our website pages and for click tracking purposes.